# Printing an array with both integers and strings in C - Not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out the board of a calculator, but don't know how to print both numbers and strings. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    int array1[4][4] = {
        {7,   8,   9,  "%"},
        {4,   5,   6,  "x"},
        {1,   2,   3,  "-"},
        {0, ".", "+",  "="}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
           {
                printf("%2i", array1[i][j]);
           }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When I compile the code, I get an error:

> error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int'
>   with an expression of type 'char [2]'

Any ideas/tips on how I can fix this?

Comment: You can't have an array with both integers and strings, so you'll need to pick one. It makes sense to pick strings because they can also contain numbers.

Comment: Arrays cannot contain different types.

Comment: FWIW, `"%"` does not give you a `char`, it gives you a `char *`, at best.

Comment: If you just want to display the items, you could use a string per row `"7 8 9 %"`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Any idea why my question was downvoted? Trying to figure it out so next time I don't make the same mistake.

Comment: Just a guess: Some might think that this question is demonstrating a lack of a very basic `C` understanding, which should be filled using dedicated resources, like books, and not really a good SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `array1` mixes integers and strings which is not allowed in `C`. For your situation you may want to switch to the char data type and use the same print statement for all of the characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char array1[4][4] = {
        {'7','8','9','%'},
        {'4','5','6','x'},
        {'1','2','3','-'},
        {'0','.','+','='}};

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", array1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Arr, always a minute late! (;

Answer (score 1):

C is [strongly typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). It means you can't just put any value in an `int` array. `int` is not something like `var` in Javascript, it's a built-in type capable of storing only numerical integer values (**not** stings!).

I can see you are trying to use only one-character long strings and one-digit numbers, maybe a more suitable type for you would be `char`:

```
char array1[4][4] = {
    {'7','8','9','%'}, 
    {'4','5','6','x'}, 
    {'1','2','3','-'},
    {'0', '.', '+','='}
};
```

And now you can print your matrix using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("%c", array1[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```